# How to solve a karmarkar's optimisation problem in scilab

Tags: optimization, scilab

i am new to scilab. i have transformed an Lp equation to the karmarka form and now i am trying to solve but it is not giving xopt. please help. the equation is shown jn the image

[image: LP transformed into karamarkar's standard form]

Comment: Where is your Scilab code ?

Comment: Aeq= [ i am inputting all the coefficients for the variables];

Answer (score 1):

I presume that you have not mentioned the positivity constraint on the components of y. In that case, you have the trivial solution:

```
c=zeros(23,1);
c(23)=1;

A=[
0.00359 0.0042 0.0021 0.00419 0.00359 0.00438 1 zeros(1,14) -4332 4332.978
0.89 1.12 1.044 0.86 0.73 0.23 0 1 zeros(1,13) -467012 467008.126
7.552 6.539 7.671 6.822 6.12 4.824 0 0 1 zeros(1,12) -163766 1637621.625
0.0135 0.0133 0.007 0.005 0.0149 0.0156 0 0 0 1 zeros(1,11) -8796 8796.931 
zeros(1,10) 0.00359 0.89  7.552 0.0135 -1 0 0 0 0 0 0 -289.45 281.869 
zeros(1,10) 0.0042  1.12  6.539 0.0133 0 -1 0 0 0 0 0 -300.49 293.814 
zeros(1,10) 0.0021  1.044 7.671 0.007  0 0 -1 0 0 0 0 -287.37  279.646 
zeros(1,10) 0.00419 0.86  6.822 0.005  0 0 0 -1 0 0 0 -288.09 274.577 
zeros(1,10) 0.00359 0.73  6.12  0.0149 0 0 0 0 -1 0 0 -290.33 284.475 
zeros(1,10) 0.00438 0.23  4.824 0.0156 0 0 0 0 0 -1 0 -317.15 313.076
];
b=zeros(10,1);

y=karmarkar(A,b,c,zeros(23,1))

WARNING: karmarkar: The algorithm did not converge (exitflag= -3).
 y  = 

   0.
   0.
   0.
   0.
   0.
   0.
   0.
   0.
   0.
   0.
   0.
   0.
   0.
   0.
   0.
   0.
   0.
   0.
   0.
   0.
   0.
   0.
```